# Sequelize how to structure the chat part of the app?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I currently have an app where users can log in and make posts. Next to each post, there is button that if pressed, the current user can send a message to the user who created the post.

I have a posts model and a user model. Each user can post as many posts as they want, but each post only belongs to one user.

```
const User = db.define(
"User",
{
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
password: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
},
);

const Post = db.define(
"Post",
{
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
subTitle: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
userId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
},
);

User.hasMany(Post,
{ foreignKey: "userId" }
);

Post.belongsTo(User, 
{ foreignKey: "userId" }
);
```

What i am trying to implement now is the messaging functionality.

Here is my messages Model so far:

```
  const Messages = db.define("Messages", {
  id: {
  allowNull: false,
  autoIncrement: true,
  primaryKey: true,
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
 senderId: {
 type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
 receiverId: {
 type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
 message: {
 type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
});

User.hasMany(Messages, {
foreignKey: 'senderId'
});

User.hasMany(Messages, {
foreignKey: 'receiverId'
});

Messages.associate = (models) => {
Messages.belongsTo(models.Post, {
foreignKey: "PostId",
});
Messages.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "senderId",
});
Messages.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "receiverId",
});
};

User.hasMany(Conversations, {
foreignKey: 'conversationId'
});
```

And here is my conversation model so far:

```
const Conversations = db.define("Conversations", {
id: {
allowNull: false,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true,
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
}
});

module.exports = Conversations;

Conversations.associate = (models) => {
Conversations.hasMany(models.Message); 
models.Message.belongsTo(Conversations); 
};
```

Also, the message can be sent from 1 user to another not to a group of users.

Are my associations and table structures correct?

*Update*

```
User.hasMany(Messages, {
foreignKey: 'senderId'
});

User.hasMany(Messages, {
foreignKey: 'receiverId'
});

Messages.associate = (models) => {
Messages.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "senderId",
});
Messages.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "receiverId",
});
Messages.belongsTo(models.Conversations,{
foreignKey: "conversationId",
});
};

Conversations.associate = (models) => {
Conversations.hasMany(models.Messages,{
  foreignKey: "conversationId",
}); 
Conversations.belongsTo(models.Post,{
  foreignKey: "PostId",
})
};

Post.hasMany(Conversations, { foreignKey: "PostId" });

User.hasMany(Conversations, {
foreignKey: 'user1'
});

User.hasMany(Conversations, {
foreignKey: 'user2'
});
```

Using this implementation when i try sending a message, the conversationId in the messages table is null.

Here is my post request:

```
router.post("/", 
auth, 
async (req, res) => {

const post = await Post.findOne({where:{id:req.body.postId}})
if (!post) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid postId." });

const targetUser = await User.findOne({where:{post.userId}})
if (!targetUser) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid 
userId." });

await Conversations.findOne({
where:{
  user1:{[Op.or]:[req.user.id,post.userId]},
  user2:{[Op.or]:[req.user.id,post.userId]},
  PostId:req.body.postId,
}
}).then(conversation=>{
if(conversation){
  return conversation
}else{
  return Conversations.create({
    user1: req.user.id,
    user2: post.userId,
    PostId:req.body.postId,
  })
}
}
)
  Messages.create({
  senderId: req.user.id,
  receiverId: post.userId,
  message: req.body.message,
  conversationId:conversation.id //MY PROBLEM IS HERE
})
.then(
  res.status(201).send({
    msg: "upload successful",
  }));

const { expoPushToken } = targetUser;

if (Expo.isExpoPushToken(expoPushToken))
await sendPushNotification(expoPushToken, message);

});
```

Comment: Can conversations not to be related to posts at all? Can they be just between any two users?

Comment: Actually yes, the conversation will be related to a post (but the same users can have different conversations about a different post). yes, a conversation is just between 2 users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All models look good. The issues are with associations.

If you define more then one association between the same two models you should indicate different aliases to distinguish them from each other in queries.

```
User.hasMany(Messages, {
foreignKey: 'senderId',
as: 'OutgoingMessages'
});

User.hasMany(Messages, {
foreignKey: 'receiverId',
as: 'IncomingMessages'
});
```

```
Messages.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "senderId",
as: 'Sender'
});
Messages.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "receiverId",
as: 'Receiver'
});
```

Also it's better to define associations in the same manner either directly after model definition or in a static method like `associate`. The latter approach is preferable because it allows to define each model in its own module without any cross-references using the `models` parameter in `associate` method to access other models that should be associated with a given model.

Last note: try to define associations where a model on the left side of an association definition in its own `associate` method.
It means that

```
models.Message.belongsTo(Conversations);
```

should be in `Message` model `associate` method:

```
Message.belongsTo(models.Conversations);
```

That way you always know where to find all associations that define links from a certain model to other models.

**UPDATE**

You should store a found or a created conversation to a variable in order to use it while creating a message:

```js
let conversation = await Conversations.findOne({
  where:{
    user1:{[Op.or]:[req.user.id,post.userId]},
    user2:{[Op.or]:[req.user.id,post.userId]},
    PostId:req.body.postId,
  }
})

if (!conversation){
  conversation = await Conversations.create({
    user1: req.user.id,
    user2: post.userId,
    PostId:req.body.postId,
  })
}
const newMessage = await Messages.create({
  senderId: req.user.id,
  receiverId: post.userId,
  message: req.body.message,
  conversationId:conversation.id
})
res.status(201).send({
  msg: "upload successful",
});
```

Don't try to mix up `then/catch` and `await`. If you use `await` you will already have a result or an exception (which you can handle using `try/catch`).

Comment: After looking at my code, i think i should remove Messages.belongsTo(models.Post, {
foreignKey: "PostId",
}); from my message model associate method and add it to my conversation model associate method, since the post can have many conversations and a conversation only belongs to 1 post. then in my messages table i add a conversationId that links each message to the specific conversation. Is that correct or should i keep postId in my messages table?

Comment: I have updated my code with the updated associations.

Comment: Yes, if a conversation is always linked to some post then `postId` should be in `Conversation` model rather then in `Message` model

Comment: i am trying to run my query based on the updated associations in the question and it is working but when i check my database the conversationId column in the messages table is always null. is this a problem with my query or association? should i add conversationId in my messages model?

Comment: I have updated my question with my post request if you can please have a look

Comment: Yes, add `conversationId` to `Messages`

Comment: Thank you alot it worked, so my problem was that i was not stored the conversation in a variable and that was why i could not use it. Also, i do not need to use newMessage variable anywhere?

Comment: Thank you alot for your time, and now to implement live rendering i need to implement socket.io correct?

Comment: Yeah, something like this. But that's a whole new bunch of questions and answers for you on SO ) Good luck!

Comment: Ok, create a new question on SO and post a link to it here

Comment: Hi Anatoly, i was testing this code out on 2 devices to see if users can send messages to each other. the functionality is not working properly,eg. if the post is created by user 1 and user 2 sends user1 a message that works. but now when user 1 tries to send user 2 a message it doesnt work. since now req.user.id = user 1 and the post.userId =user1

Comment: And where do you store `user2` id?

Comment: so initially when the current user sends a message to the post user, in my conversation table user1 (current user) and user2 (post user) get stored. Now user2 wants to reply to user1's message

Comment: I mean do you have `user2` id at hand right before a query?

Comment: actually i dont think so, since when user1 sends the initial message user 1 and user 2 get stored in conversation table. when user2 tries to reply i creates a new conversation between user 2 and user 2 since user 2 is now both the post user and the current user

Comment: I suppose if a conversation already exists why don't you just send a conversation id to a backend when either the first or send user replies to each other?

Comment: so i should create a new end point for when a conversation exists?

Comment: with the implementation using the code above, when i try to reply the query first checks if a conversation exists where user1(is either the current user or post user) and user2(is either the current user or post user) which in the case of reply they are both the same user and thats why it creates a new conversation

Comment: Hi Anatoly, do you suggest i create a new endpoint for sending messages within chat?

Comment: Yes, it seems logical to have two routes: 1. create a conversation (along with a message) 2. create a message in an existing conversation

Comment: Thank you Anatoly. And in the 2nd route, i findOne where the conversation id from the body exists in the conversation table then i create a message?

Comment: Exactly! Something like POST /conversation/{id}/messages

Comment: Oh ok, so findByPk then, where id is the conversation id. Again thank you alot for clarifying things appreciate it :)

Comment: But my senderId and receiverId in my messages table they will be either user 1 or user 2 from conversation table depend on who sent the message correct?

Comment: If you get all conversation messages then yes you can add a condition about senderId and receiverId using `OR`

Comment: As of adding messages it's easy: a current user is `senderId` and the second user of a conversation will be receiverId